# Facebook graph api and keep alive connections

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, keep-alive

We want to reduce the https connect latency to facebook graph servers. We have configured our servers to do a http keep alive. However, it looks like the connection gets closed after every call (from traffic server logs...).

Is there a way to deterministically see that keep_alive connections are honored or not by graph.facebook.com? ..or for that matter any server in general?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Facebook's attitude towards efficient queries, I would not expect them to honor any type of persistent connection. Especially since your request is going to end up in a performance hit on their servers.

You should look at fetching as much data as you can in one go by combining your queries into a single [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

Comment: Actually, I see that facebook supports connection: keep-alive as their response contains that header.. a simple curl -v query1 query2... and a tcpdump reveals there is FIN only at the end..